# findIndex alternative for IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, sticky

I have this code for navigation scroll to section .

```
var lastId;
    var topMenu = $(".community-nav");   
    var topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() - 19; 
    if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches){
        var logoHeight = $(".community-logo").outerHeight();
        var topMenuHeight =  topMenu.outerHeight() - logoHeight;
    };
    menuItems = topMenu.find('.community-links li > div'),
    scrollItems = $('.nav-section')


      menuItems.click(function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr("data-target");
        var currentItem = $(this);
        var sectionClass = $("#community-intranav");
        scrollPartialMenuItem(currentItem, sectionClass);    
        var offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight + 20;
         if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches){


          };
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 850);
        e.preventDefault();
      });

      function getCurrentSection(scrollPosition) {
        return scrollItems.toArray().findIndex(function(item) {
          return item.offsetTop < scrollPosition && item.offsetTop+item.clientHeight > scrollPosition;
        });
      }

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).on("load scroll",function(e){    
        var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
        var currentSection = getCurrentSection(scrollPosition) ;
        var id = currentSection > -1 ? scrollItems[currentSection].id : "";

        if (id && lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
        menuItems.removeClass("active");
        menuItems.filter("[data-target='#"+id+"']").addClass('active');
        }                   
     });
```

In the above code,the findIndex method is supported in IE.I want an alternative for the same so that I can rewrite my function  getCurrentSection using something other than the findIndex method.Please help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill

Comment: Do you know what findIndex does? How it works?

Comment: Isn't your code already using `findIndex`? You could elaborate the question. The title says you want to find an findIndex alternative for IE, then the text says IE supports findIndex, and you want something else. Then in the comment you say you want  findIndex. Please clean this mess.

Comment: yes.But it does not have IE support and that is why I want to rewrite it so that it supports IE.

Comment: The linked MDN page shows how you can make IE to support findIndex ...

Comment: Better? How? Why? If you'd polyfill findIndex, you could use it anywhere in your code, instead of making all things in a hard way ... A polyfill is just a regular script you add to the page, as a separate (collection of polyfills) script or a part of your own script file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a polly fill to add the missing features such as this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill

add this to your code

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.findindex
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'findIndex', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return k.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return k;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return -1.
      return -1;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

Or you can make use of a pollyfill service cdn like **pollyfill.io**

```
 <script src='https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features?feature=Array.prototype.findIndex'>
    </script>
```

Comment: Polyfills are to be added directly to the script file?Never used polyfills .

Comment: Yes you can directly use Polly fills in your script tag. or ypu could make use of some pollyfill cdn service like polyfill.io  

whats great with this is this dynamically change the pollyfill according to the browser you are using   

add this to your body and rest will be handled by pollyfill.io  


`<script src='https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features?feature=Array.prototype.findIndex'></script>`